# JQuery JSON image upload to Node.JS

Tags: jquery, node.js, image, upload

I am trying to upload an image to node.js, which works just fine with this following code:

*Client side:*

```
$("#portrait-upload").change(function(e) {
  var data = e.target.files[0];

  $.ajax({
    url: "/upload",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: "multipart/form-data",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

*Server side:*

```
if(req.url == "/upload"){
  var image = fs.createWriteStream("temp.jpg");

  req.on("data", function(chunk) {
    image.write(chunk);
    res.write("Data received.\n");
  });

  req.on("end", function() {
    image.end();
    res.end("Data reception ended.");
  });
}
```

Additionally though, I want to read the file's name on the server side. Apparently, I cannot read it out of the request object (at least I did not find a proper method). So I thought POSTing a JSON object with both the file's name and the file itself - something like this:

```
{ filename : data.name, file: data }
```

But this does apparently not work - is it even possible to put image-data into a JSON object like that and read it out on the server?

What would be a better method of transmitting both the file's name and the image file itself to node?

Thanks

Comment: you can use external modules for this, like [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the file name as a GET parameter instead of POST.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, this is actually how I did it since I do not want to use express or formidable yet - I want to stick to "basic" Node modules for now.

For anyone needing the same thing - this is the client:
$.get("/upload", { filename : image.name }).done(function(response) { console.log(response) });

Server side:
Inside the http.createServer callback:
if((request.url).indexOf("/upload") > -1) {
console.log(url.parse(request.url).query);
}